# ¿Es buena pratica que los elementos rebosen mi grilla?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto usando css grid y note que los elementos imagenes rebosan el espacio asignado de mi grilla ¿esto puede causar algun problema?
[image: mi grilla]

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y trata de dar un mejor contexto a tu duda

Comment: Estaría muy bueno que compartas tu CSS, si tengo que adivinar es por un problema las propiedades. Pero no, no es una buena práctica. Lo ideal es que siempre esté perfecto.

Comment: Alguna regla del layout CSS (`.container` quiza) esta impidiendo que el alto de la celda se ajuste al alto de la imagen, puedes compartir el CSS relevante al caso ( las clases container* por lo menos), y revisa si hay reglas como `height` o `max-height` que sean mayores que el alto de las imagenes